# Why aren't "NOT IN" and "NOT EXISTS" working?

Tags: mysql, not-exists, notin

I've tried to accomplish this in a few different ways, and I'm coming up short. I'm trying to figure out the IDs of clients who have not scheduled an appointment this year.

My first query takes *forever*, and times out most of the time:

```
SELECT c.clientId
FROM clients c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT a.appointmentId FROM appointments a WHERE a.date >= "2020-02-15" AND c.clientId = a.clientId)
```

My second query is super fast, but that's likely because it's not taking the NOT IN into account.  The results show the same thing as if I run the query without the NOT EXISTS.  I think this means I'm not properly matching up a.clientId = c.clientId.  But, I can't seem to figure out how to make that work.

```
SELECT c.clientId
FROM clients c
WHERE c.clientId NOT IN (
    SELECT a.appointmentId FROM appointments a WHERE a.date >= "2020-02-15")
```

I also tried it this third way with no luck, it returns an empty set:

```
SELECT c.clientId
FROM clients c
LEFT JOIN appointments a
ON a.clientId = c.clientId
WHERE a.appointmentId IS NULL
AND a.date >= '2020-02-15'
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your second query is that you're comparing `clientId` in `client` with `appointmentId` in `appointments`, so it's unlikely to do any filtering. It should be written as

```
SELECT clientId
FROM clients
WHERE clientId NOT IN (
    SELECT clientId FROM appointments WHERE date >= "2020-02-15")
```

The issue with your third query is that the `a.date >= '2020-02-15'` condition in the `WHERE` clause effectively turns your `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN` (see the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/outer-join-optimization.html)), thus `a.appointmentId IS NULL` is never true. You need to add the `date` comparison to the `JOIN` condition:

```
SELECT c.clientId
FROM clients c
LEFT JOIN appointments a
ON a.clientId = c.clientId AND a.date >= '2020-02-15'
WHERE a.appointmentId IS NULL
```

Note that if *all* you want is the `clientId` value, you don't need to use the `clients` table at all:

```
SELECT clientId
FROM appointments
GROUP BY clientId
HAVING MAX(date) < '2020-02-15'
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ijpVakqXicAvVDjLiVqgVR/0)

Comment: Great catch on the second query.  I can't believe I missed that after playing with it all afternoon.  But even with the modification, it still returns the same number as without the NOT IN clause.  Running the third query now and it's taking a while, but the database is pretty big.  I'll mark this if it works!

Comment: Yes, your modification to the third query worked.  I really appreciate your help.  I can't mark an answer for another 3 minutes, but wanted to let you know.  The second query does the same thing even if I have WHERE 1 NOT IN..., so I'm not sure why it's deciding to ignore that altogether.

Comment: @radleybobins I've added a demo which shows the second query working. Also I've added another alternate query which should be even faster if *all* you want is the `clientId` value.

Comment: I know you're supposed to keep it strictly business in the comments, but I just wanted to thank you again and apologize for not responding to your updated Demo.  I came down with a case of food poisoning and I'm just getting back to normal.  Your answer and comments were super helpful, and I can't thank you enough for getting me over the hump.

Comment: @radleybobins no problem at all - sorry to hear about the food poisoning, I know just how bad that can be. Anyway, I'm glad it was helpful.